# Problems submitting separate HTML forms

Tags: html, forms

So I'm having a problem creating the UI for a webpage designed to use buttons to send predetermined messages. Each button is its own form, and the idea is when the submit button is pressed for a unique message to be sent.

The problem I'm having right now is that my PHP backend requires that the `form id` attribute be referenced to the message recipient stored in the database so it knows who to send the message to, so I cannot use `form id` to distinguish between forms otherwise the backend will fail and the message will not be sent. Right now no matter which button is pressed it is submitting the first form. Is there any way for separate `submit` buttons to submit a specified form without using `form id`?

Here is a sample of my code that shows the problem:

```
<td>
<form id="<?php echo $row[" id "] ?>" name="hello" method="post" onsubmit="return sendPushNotification('<?php echo $row[" id "] ?>')">
    <input type="hidden" name="message" value="hello" />
    <input type="hidden" name="regId" value="<?php echo $row[" gcm_regid "] ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" class="send_btn" value="Send Hello" />
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <form id="<?php echo $row[" id "] ?>" name="Goodbye" method="post" onsubmit="return sendPushNotification('<?php echo $row[" id "] ?>')">
        <input type="hidden" name="message" value="Goodbye!" />
        <input type="hidden" name="regId" value="<?php echo $row[" gcm_regid "] ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" class="send_btn" value="Send Goodbye" />
    </form>
</td>
```

In this case, both buttons would send the "hello" message since it comes first. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is the javascript for `sendPushNotification` if it helps

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

        });
        function sendPushNotification(id){
            var data = $('form#'+id).serialize();
            $('form#'+id).unbind('submit');                
            $.ajax({
                url: "send_message.php",
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                      $('.txt_message').val("");
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: both forms have the same id, and send it as param.. etc. Maybe you could concatenate some text or remove id property

Comment: So what you're saying is that if the forms have the same id it is not possible to distinguish them and this is going to have to be fixed from the backed?

Comment: not exactly. The html is not valid, you can not have two objects with the same id. Whatever makes sendPushNotification function is not able to recognize who invokes. Try with sendPushNotification(this) to send the correct form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qWE3A/1)

HTML

```
onsubmit="return sendPushNotification(this);"
```

JS

```
function sendPushNotification(formObj){
    var data = $(formObj).serialize();
            ...
```